# Did Ryu have an affair or was it Maki?

Tags: argento-soma

Did Ryu have the affair and that's why Maki wrote "Liar" to Ryu? Or did Ryu's friend make that up?

Comment: It wasn't clear to me either. Best way to find out would be asking a Japanese speaker who could look it up in forums.